# Replicate IIS setup from one machine to another

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

Looked for an answer to this and didn't see it.

This is for IIS 6.0 / Windows Server 2003.

I'm working with an extremely large ASP/ASP.NET application and I'm trying to get my development environment to match my team members environment. This process is basically trial and error: get an error, go into IIS, make a change, hope the error is fixed. Ugh. I'm hoping to find a way to **replicate a set of IIS directories and their configurations** on one machine onto my machine.

I did find a script that will iterate through and give me a list of all virtual directories on a machine. It helped, but not a lot since I still have to go in and set up all those virtual directories (I think there are like 20 of them ballpark). The whole process is complicated by the fact that we're mixing ASP and ASP.NET applications in the same application which spans many solutions and projects. Getting the whole thing up and going seems like way too much work but I've never heard of a real solution to this.

Would Powershell be helpful here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should export and import IIS metabase.

These might help:

- [IIS Settings Replication](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2006/06/07/IISCnfg.vbs---IIS-Settings-Replication.aspx)
- [IIS Metabase Backup and Restore](http://web-developer.boeldt.net/IIS_Metabase_Backup.asp)

Fortunately, in IIS7, ASP.NET config is integrated with IIS config so the job is done by copying `Web.config`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's Microsofts' documentation for iiscnfg. [iiscnfg documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/81f04967-f02f-4845-9795-bad2fe1a1687.mspx?mfr=true)

When I ran it the first time, I got an error that said "This script does not work with WScript."  If that happens to you:

```
1. Click OK.
2. At the "Would you like to register Cscript as your default host for VBscript?" click Yes.
3. At "Successfully registered Cscript" click OK.
4. Run the command again
```